# Group by query causing incorrect data to appear

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to right a report to get a breakdown of all the ethnicities in my system by gender.

I have this query that I thought was working, but all of the dates are the same in the query, which they are NOT in the individual tables. I think the group_by is causing an issue, but i'm not 100% and i'm not sure how to properly right this query.

```
SELECT f1.field_name, count(*) AS total
FROM application_fields f1
JOIN application_fields_values v1 ON v1.application_field_id = f1.id
JOIN application_fields_values v2 ON v1.applicant_id = v2.applicant_id
JOIN application_fields f2 ON v2.application_field_id = f2.id
JOIN templates t ON f1.template_id = t.id
JOIN template_fields tf ON f1.template_field_id = tf.id
WHERE v1.field_value = 1
AND v2.field_value = 1
AND f2.field_name = 'Male'
AND f1.field_name != 'Male'
-- AND f1.created_at BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2014-12-31'
AND tf.id IN (9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15)
GROUP BY f1.field_name
ORDER BY f1.id;
```

This outputs:

```
FIELD_NAME          CREATED_AT              CREATED_AT          TOTAL
Hispanic or Latino. 2013-06-20 02:35:56     2013-06-20 02:35:56   6
Caucasion.          2013-06-20 02:35:56     2013-06-20 02:35:56   26
African American.   2013-06-20 02:35:56     2013-06-20 02:35:56   25
Native Hawaiian.    2013-06-20 02:35:56     2013-06-20 02:35:56   1
Asian.              2013-06-20 02:35:56     2013-06-20 02:35:56   2
American Indian.    2013-06-20 02:35:56     2013-06-20 02:35:56   2
Two or more races . 2013-06-20 02:35:56     2013-06-20 02:35:56   1
```

I want to be able to filter this by date (as you can see in my commented out line) but that's not working correctly since all the dates are the same in this query when they most definitely are not in the tables themselves.

Comment: Even though MySQL allows you to mismatch the select and group by clauses, I've yet to see it being a good idea.

Comment: I only added the `created_at` dates in the query to debug it. If I take those `created_at` fields out of the select statement, i'm still not getting data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that I was looking at the wrong tables `created_at` column in the between clause.

```
AND f1.created_at BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2014-12-31'
```

should have been

```
AND v1.created_at BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2014-12-31'
```

Answer (score 2):

Each non-aggregate field in your select list should be included in your `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT f1.field_name, f1.created_at, f2.created_at, count(*) AS total
FROM application_fields f1
JOIN application_fields_values v1 ON v1.application_field_id = f1.id
JOIN application_fields_values v2 ON v1.applicant_id = v2.applicant_id
JOIN application_fields f2 ON v2.application_field_id = f2.id
JOIN templates t ON f1.template_id = t.id
JOIN template_fields tf ON f1.template_field_id = tf.id
WHERE v1.field_value = 1
  AND v2.field_value = 1
  AND f2.field_name = 'Male'
  AND f1.field_name != 'Male'
  -- AND f1.created_at BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2014-12-31'
  AND tf.id IN (9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15)
GROUP BY f1.field_name, f1.created_at, f2.created_at
ORDER BY f1.id;
```

MySQL does not require that all fields be included in the `GROUP BY`, but without them the returned values are arbitrary.

If there are multiple values for the fields you haven't included in your `GROUP BY` then rather than include them in your `GROUP BY` you may need to use an aggregate function on them, ie:

```
SELECT f1.field_name, MAX(f1.created_at), MAX(f2.created_at), count(*) AS total
FROM application_fields f1
JOIN application_fields_values v1 ON v1.application_field_id = f1.id
JOIN application_fields_values v2 ON v1.applicant_id = v2.applicant_id
JOIN application_fields f2 ON v2.application_field_id = f2.id
JOIN templates t ON f1.template_id = t.id
JOIN template_fields tf ON f1.template_field_id = tf.id
WHERE v1.field_value = 1
  AND v2.field_value = 1
  AND f2.field_name = 'Male'
  AND f1.field_name != 'Male'
  -- AND f1.created_at BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2014-12-31'
  AND tf.id IN (9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15)
GROUP BY f1.field_name
ORDER BY f1.id;
```

Comment: See my comment on the question.

Comment: Nothing sticks out from the query apart from the `GROUP BY` issue, not sure what else can be done without knowing the data a bit better.

Answer (score 1):

You're grouping by one column only (`f1.field_name`) but you include more columns in the `select` clause. Such grouping is allowed in MySQL but should really be discouraged as it may lead to such results as you have.

The problem is that you probably have different dates (`f1.created_at`, `f2.created_at`) for the same grouping field `f1.field_name` so it's not possible to select just one unique value of those dates for each group. In this case, logically you shouldn't be including such fields (without any aggregate functions) in the `select` clause.

You can also add `f1.created_at` and `f2.created_at` to `group by` clause but this will give you results broken by the dates which is probably not what you need.